# I am working on some project where i have to take value from memory address and came across this expression

Tags: c, pointers, memory

How to interpret this expression

`(*(int *)((char *)P + value ))`

initially P was set to null.

where P =  some memory address.

value = some hexadecimal value read from a file.

Can someone explain what this expression is doing?

Comment: The expression is treating the unknown type `P` pointer as a `char *` pointer, computing some address `value` octets from the base address stored in `P`, casting the resulting `char*` as `int*`, then dereferencing the result of that to acquire whatever integer happens to be laying at that location. This is also an exercise in  praying to the bus-alignment gods that your platform won't fault when you land on a non-aligned address and attempt to extract an `int` from it.

Comment: In addition to alignment issues, it is also a likely strict aliasing violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void *p = NULL;   // defines void pointer holding NULL pointer value.

p = 0x456789;     // assignes p with whe integer value connverted to (void *). 
                  //On many systems this integer value represents the memory address

int x = *(int *)((char *)p + value);
                  // 1. casts p to the char pointer.
                  // 2. Adds value chars to the pointer value. Usually char is 8 bits
                  //    so the referenced object will be "value" bytes ahead of 
                  //    the original pointed location
                  // 3. Casts this pointer to the the pointer to int
                  // 4. Dereferences (reads) the integer pointed by the pointer
```

This kind of operations generally invoke a UB in the standard C. How it will behave depends on the implementation. It is very common operation in the low-level programming (hardware registers).

Comment: intially it is `char *p= null` and value is in hexadecimal.